# NodeJS resolve promise after loop complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

How can I resolve this promise after the last promise in the loop is fulfilled?

```
var foo = function(JSONArray){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        for(var i=0; i < JSONArray.length; i++){
            doIntensiveWork(JSONArray[i])
            .then(doMoreIntensiveWork) //returns a promise
        }

        //resolve() after every promise from the loop is fulfilled
    })
}
```

I use [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisejoinpromisethenablevalue-promises-function-handler---promise)

Comment: `->` https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise

Comment: I think the bluebird docs give more than enough of an explanation of this.  Check out all the cool collection methods that are in the library, I think you'll find them quite powerful.

Answer (score 3):

With [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper--object-options---promise).

```
var foo = function(array) {
    return new Promise.map(array, function(element) {
        return doIntensiveWork(element).then(doMoreIntensiveWork);
    });
};

foo(['bar', 'baz'])
.then(function(returnedValues) {
    // returnedValues is an array containing all values
    // return by your intensive work in foo
});
```

Comment: `Promise.map` runs concurrently, does not preserve iteration order and generally does not do what OP's original code (minus incorrect returning) does.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I don't see any indication in the OP that the work should not be done concurrently. `Promise.map` seems to be just the way to go here.

Comment: I didn't know `map` didn't preserve the order. About the concurrency it can be set with `...map(..., {concurrency: 1});`. If return order is important he can use `all`.

Comment: It preserves the order in the array, but 7th item in the list might complete before 3rd item, however that should never matter for a legit mapping operation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise#each`:

```
var foo = function(jsonArray){
     return Promise.each(jsonArray, doIntensiveWork).each(doMoreIntensiveWork);
});
```

Comment: Would this wait for all `doIntensiveWork`s before starting with the first `doMoreIntensiveWork`?

Comment: @Bergi to be fair I don't remember, it's entirely possible that there is an optimization here (like in `.map`) or that Petka chose not to implement one yet. Either way it doesn't sound like a huge deal to me since OP wants to wait for all jobs to be done serially anyway based on the original codeand I assume this will take about as long.